# ruby on rails logging out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am trying to create a view which allows the user to log out

So what what I've got is:

```
<%= link_to 'log out', :controller => "client", :action => "logout", :id => session[:id] %>
```

but this gives me this error:

> No route matches "/client/logout/Lily"
>   with {:method=>:get}

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you defined route to that action? Defned that `logout` is action retrieved with GET?

```
map.resource :user, :collection => {:logout => :get}
```

Comment: im not too familiar with these (all i know is that what you suggested worked - so I thank you) where can I learn more pls?
thx again!!!

Comment: @Lily That part was from documentation: <http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000523>. I think there is no good tutorial to get all that things, check example applications on github and search documentation <http://rubyonrails.org/documentation>.

For that part about resources, you should remember that rails only give you mapping for `index`,`new`,`create`,`edit`,`update` and `delete` methods, all other you need to specify by youself

Comment: @Lily: If this answer worked for you, why not vote it up and mark it as an answer?